# Chaning the overlap in wp7 panorma control

Tags: windows-phone-7, panorama-control

By default the next item in wp7 panorama bleeds into the currently selected panorama item by a few pixels and I would like to show a bit more of the next item.

Is there a way to control the amount of pixels? I tried setting margins and paddings and tried editing the controlTemplate, but had no success.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this, aren't you going to be breaking the design guidelines for the Panorama control, therefore the control is no longer a Panorama control, making your application inconsistant with other applications using the unmodified version of the control?

Comment: Yes and no. The items will still bleed over and the functionality stays the same. This is pure astethics. Not sure how rigid Microsoft are with the design guidelines in this case. If its' not possible to change it that easy I assume its supposed to be this way.

Comment: Microsoft is not rigid with design guidelines.  If you want to make something that doesn't conform, you're more than welcome to.  They strongly encourage the metro design, though, and (in my opinion) a metro approach is going to make your app more appealing.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a panorama item a negative margin:

Margin="-24,0,0,0"

Comment: This will only work until you swipe to the next panorama item. It will be cut off on the left than.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the way to do this is to wrap the content of the panoramaItem into a WrapPanel and set the orientation of the panoramaItem to horizontal.